# change ), in string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, preg-replace

I want to change string with JavaScript, I have string which includes `),` and I want to have only comma, I try it :

```
fields = fields.replace(/),/g , '');
```

but this is results in an error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the parenthesis because the regex engine assume it as a close capture group and replace with `,` :

```
fields = fields.replace(/\),/g , ',');
```

Comment: you forgot to replace with `,`, Op wants to keep `,`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
fields = fields.replace(/\),/g , ',');
```

You need to escape the `)` with `\)` and replace `''` with `','`.  When using replace it will replace the entire match from the first argument with the second argument.  Since you include the `,` in your match you need to add it back in your replace...